# select where comma-separted-string field contains a value from a list of strings

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

Table **B** has a field called 'tagged'. It is a string of comma-separated numbers, e.g.

```
454545,324512,234,345234
```

**idList** is a List of long numbers.

I want to get (a list of) all items in **B**, that one of the numbers in their 'tagged' field is contained within idLIST.

Trying:

```
context.B.Where(b => b.tagged.Split(',').ToList().Any(t => idList.ConvertAll<string>(f => f.ToString()).Contains(t))).ToList();
```

Gives me an exception with:

```
System.String[] Split(Char[])' has no supported translation to SQL
```

:(

(Note that I'm aware I can convert the long list to a string list beforehand, outside of the query, but it's not relevant to the question :) ).

Comment: Is this EF? there is a tight limit on what can a lambda do since it has to be translated to SQL

Comment: It would have horrible performance but you could do something using Like(',324512,') though I'm not sure how you'd do that in linq-to-sql.

Comment: You shouldn't be storing comma separated values in a relational table in the first place. Think about re-designing (normalize) your data model.

Comment: Peer pressure worked. There is now a new separate table for this in the DB. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SqlMethods.Like`, but it's really better to add table for ids.